# How to “disable” zoom on a mobile web page?

Tags: meta-tags

I know this question has been asked many times and has different solutions, but I have a different problem.

```
<meta content='True' name='HandheldFriendly' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

If i add the above code to my aspx page, the page zooms automatically to max size. How do I fix this? With out the above code, the web page zooms only on text box focus. I have used a liquid CSS layout for my web page.

Answer (score 0):

i want to answer the question but need more information.

do you want to disable zoom?
 if so do you want it default zoomed in OR default zoomed out.

mobile doc type helps :
 !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd"

if you do not want to disable zoom let me know what you are trying to do or please link to your url.